# Daterangepicker unclickable old date

Tags: javascript, daterangepicker

I'm using [this](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) JavaScript component for choosing date ranges, and I have a problem in the UI.

[image]

As you can see in the image, you can select any date in the left calendar and what I'm trying to do is a hotel reservation system. The right calendar works perfectly while the left is not. How can I deactivate or make the old dates unclickable? Is there a hack for this?

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="reservation" id="reservation" class="input-daterange form-control pull-right active">
```

**Initialization code:**

```
$('.input-daterange').daterangepicker({
      "opens": "right"
});
```

In my php file, I can validate it with this:

```
$reservation = explode("-", \Request::input('reservation'));
$from        = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($reservation[0]));
$to          = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($reservation[1]));

$now  = new DateTime("today");
$day1 = new DateTime($from);
$day2 = new DateTime($to);
$diff = date_diff($day1, $day2, true);
$days = $diff->format('%a');

if ($day1 > $day2 || $day1 < $now || $days == 0) {
    echo "invalid";
}
```

But what if I want to do it directly in the UI?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap datetimepicker?

Comment: @K.D, Oh, I don't know but I provided the javascript component I am using in the post

Comment: can you post your datetimepicker initialization code to you question?

Comment: @K.D Sure, updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code might work try this:

```
 var todayDate = new Date();
 var todayMin = new Date(todayDate.getFullYear(), todayDate.getMonth(), todayDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
 $('.input-daterange').daterangepicker({
    "opens": "right",
    "minDate": todayMin
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do like below code :-

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 3,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate: 0", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 3,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
```

It will generate a restricted date range.

```
$(".input-daterange").datepicker({dateFormat:'mm/dd/yy', minDate: new Date(2010,11,12) });
```

you can try this also.